# Match digit optionally in string

Tags: regex

I would like to match something like (both):

- `I have "arbitrary string"`
- `I have 50 "arbitrary string"`

I came up with: `/^I have (\d+)? "([^"]*)"$/` to match 2nd, but doesn't do with first one.

How to make the digit optional? I need the data in digit.

Thanks.

Comment: Your regex still requires two spaces around the optional digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `space` + digits inside a  non-capturing group and make it as optional. If you want to capture digits then put capturing group ie, `()` around `\d+`

```
^I have(?: (\d+))? "([^"]*)"$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bK0xJ8/1)

Comment: Thanks! I missed the extra grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression doesn't match the first example string since it requires a total of two space characters between `have` and `"`.

Changing the expression to `/^I have ?(\d+)? "([^"]*)"$/` fixes it (i.e, let the first space be optional).

Comment: You are right, I will accept it also to be fair. That's why in first answer we need the space after the colon `(?: (`